# Pandas - Fill NaN using multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, missing-data

I have a column ( lets call it Column X) containing around 16000 NaN values. The column has two possible values, 1 or 0 ( so like a binary )

I want to fill the NaN values in column X, but i don't want to use a single value for ALL the NaN entries.

say for instance that; i want to fill 50% of the NaN values with '1' and the other 50% with '0'.

I have read the ' fillna() ' documentation but i have not found any such relevant information which could satisfy this functionality.

I have literally no idea on how to move forward regarding this problem, so i haven't tried anything.

```
df['Column_x'] = df['Column_x'].fillna(df['Column_x'].mode()[0], inplace= True)
```

but this would fill ALL the NaN values in Column X of my dataframe 'df' with the mode of the column, i want to fill 50% with one value and other 50% with a different value.

Since i haven't tried anything yet, i can't show or describe any actual results.

what i can tell is that the expected result would be something along the lines of 8000 NaN values of column x replaced with '1' and another 8000 with '0' .

A visual result would be something like;

Before Handling NaN

```
Index     Column_x
0          0.0
1          0.0
2          0.0
3          0.0
4          0.0
5          0.0
6          1.0
7          1.0
8          1.0
9          1.0
10         1.0
11         1.0
12         NaN
13         NaN
14         NaN
15         NaN
16         NaN
17         NaN
18         NaN
19         NaN
```

After Handling NaN

```
Index     Column_x
0          0.0
1          0.0
2          0.0
3          0.0
4          0.0
5          0.0
6          1.0
7          1.0
8          1.0
9          1.0
10         1.0
11         1.0
12         0.0
13         0.0
14         0.0
15         0.0
16         1.0
17         1.0
18         1.0
19         1.0
```

Comment: Is there some rule on whether a 0 or 1 should be filled? If it should be random, you could try to fill the NaN-values with random floats between 0 and 1 and then round them.

Comment: Do the NaNs have to have exact (or as closely as possible) 50-50% 1s and 0s?

Comment: @Carsten it has to be 0 or 1 because i am handling missing data in a column that can only have 1 or 0. A 50-50 ratio would be very important to keep the column in a balanced form ( the data could be skewed without the ratio being respected ) 

can you tell me how i can fill the NaN with a random manner, like you say ?

Comment: @Chris if i vary the 50-50 ratio in filling the NaNs, it could skew the data. that is why i am insisting.

but please do share if you have any approach which can help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pandas.Series.sample`:

```
mask = df['Column_x'].isna() 
ind = df['Column_x'].loc[mask].sample(frac=0.5).index
df.loc[ind, 'Column_x'] = 1
df['Column_x'] = df['Column_x'].fillna(0)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Index  Column_x
0       0       0.0
1       1       0.0
2       2       0.0
3       3       0.0
4       4       0.0
5       5       0.0
6       6       1.0
7       7       1.0
8       8       1.0
9       9       1.0
10     10       1.0
11     11       1.0
12     12       1.0
13     13       0.0
14     14       1.0
15     15       0.0
16     16       0.0
17     17       1.0
18     18       1.0
19     19       0.0
```

Comment: Thank you ! 

This worked exactly as i needed it to

Answer (score 4):

You can use `random.choices` with its weights parameter to ensure the distribution stays the same. I've simulated a NaN column with numpy here, and get the exact length of the replacement needed. This approach can also be used for columns with more than two classes and more complex distributions.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': range(16000)})
df['col2'] = np.nan

nans = df['col2'].isna()
length = sum(nans)
replacement = random.choices([0, 1], weights=[.5, .5], k=length)
df.loc[nans,'col2'] = replacement

print(df.describe())

'''
Out:
               col1          col2
count  16000.000000  16000.000000
mean    7999.500000      0.507625
std     4618.946489      0.499957
min        0.000000      0.000000
25%     3999.750000      0.000000
50%     7999.500000      1.000000
75%    11999.250000      1.000000
max    15999.000000      1.000000
'''
```

Comment: Hey Ivan ! I see your answer will allow handling of more sophisticated cases.

Thank you for adding a new dimension to the scope of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `slicing columns` and fill value

- `isnull()` - function detect missing values in the given series object

**Ex.**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column_y': pd.Series(range(9), index=['a', 'b', 'c','d','e','f','g','h','i']),
                   'Column_x': pd.Series(range(1), index=['a'])})

print(df)
# get list of index series which have NaN Column_x value
idx = df['Column_x'].index[df['Column_x'].isnull()]
total_nan_len = len(idx)
first_nan = total_nan_len//2
# fill first 50% of 1
df.loc[idx[0:first_nan], 'Column_x'] = 1
# fill last 50% of 0
df.loc[idx[first_nan:total_nan_len], 'Column_x'] = 0
print(df)
```

**O/P:**

Before Dataframe

```
   Column_y  Column_x
a         0       0.0
b         1       NaN
c         2       NaN
d         3       NaN
e         4       NaN
f         5       NaN
g         6       NaN
h         7       NaN
i         8       NaN
```

After Dataframe

```
   Column_y  Column_x
a         0       0.0
b         1       1.0
c         2       1.0
d         3       1.0
e         4       1.0
f         5       0.0
g         6       0.0
h         7       0.0
i         8       0.0
```