# How should I replace values proportionally to 'NaN' values in a data frame by using another column?

Tags: python, dataframe, fillna

I'm trying to fill NaN data with appropriate ones based on observed relations between two categorical data in a crosstab.

[image]

So far, I learned how to replace it using this formula:

```
train.loc[train.Outlet_Type =='Grocery Store','Outlet_Size']='Small'
```

but what if I want to replace NaN values with 3 different values instead of just one(e.g "small", "Medium", "High") proportionally based on the proportion of each value in the above cross table for "Supermarket Type1".

I'd appreciate it if you can advise me regarding this issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate little bit your question? Basically you wanted to replace NaN with different values and with some criteria, if i'm not wrong. isn't it?

Comment: Please check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586275/pandas-fill-nan-using-multiple-values?noredirect=1&lq=1

this might get you in some direction.

Comment: @Ravikumar it was quite useful, thanks, However, I am looking for a solution to fill "NA" values with more than 2 values, not like the one's been mentioned on that post. imagine a situation that we face 20000 NA values and we need to fill them with 100 values proportionally to improve the accuracy of the model, it's too time-consuming to apply that method. do you have any suggestions regarding that? I was thinking of putting that line of code in a loop and giving "frac' argument in the sample() function a list of proportion, but honestly, I am not expert enough to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this [Related solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586275/pandas-fill-nan-using-multiple-values) for replacing NaN with multiple values

this might get you in some direction.

Comment: I'm sorry... this is not an answer. So, I suggest posting this in the comments